# Additional field while serializing django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am a newbie to django rest framework and have created a sample `Employee` model.

My **models.py**:

```
class Employees(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My **serializers.py**:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employees
        fields = ('first_name','last_name')
```

This works fine but I want an additional field `full_name`, which will be `first_name + last_name`.

How do I define this new field `full_name` in my `serializers.py`?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I see two ways here (I prefer the first way since you can reuse it in other parts of the app):

**add a calculated property to your model and add it to your serializer**
by using [a readonly field with source=](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#core-arguments)

```
# models.py
class Employees(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name

# serializers.py
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.Field(source='full_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Employees
        fields = ('first_name','last_name', 'full_name')
```

**by using [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#serializermethodfield)**
(your model unchanged)

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_full_name')

    def get_full_name(self, obj):
        return obj.first_name + obj.last_name

    class Meta:
        model = Employees
        fields = ('first_name','last_name', 'full_name')
```

Comment: For me, using `serializers.Field` gave an error. `serializers.ReadOnlyField` does work if `to_representation` is not defined and the view is read-only.

Comment: I have just had the same problem (I am not serializing a Django model, but another plain class) and after having banged my head on it for a while I found out that it works fine if you use `full_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField()`, i.e. discarding the `source` parameter altogether. As the [documentation says](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/) about the `source` parameter: it defaults to the name of the field. Ans it works even if it's a method (or a property)

Comment: For me (django 1.11.13) there is no need to declare the field in the serializer, just declare it in the Model and list it in the Meta.fields.

Comment: Note: `full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()` will automatically resolve to `def get_full_name(self, obj):`. Only specify the method name if it doesn't follow the naming style: `get_${field_name}`

Answer (score 7):

Provided that the `Employee` is a login user, then most of us will use `django.auth.User`, I will share how `Employee` can be implemented as another `Profile` (extension of django User). Also with the addition of `full_name.read_only`, `first_name.write_only`, and `last_name.write_only`

```
# models.py
class Employee(models.Model):
    """User Profile Model"""
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')

# serializers.py
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='user.email')

    first_name = serializers.CharField(
            source='user.first_name', write_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(
            source='user.last_name', write_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(
            source='user.get_full_name', read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = (
            'url', 'username', 'email',
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'name')
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

SerializerMethodField works fine, and we can also store data in serializer object and let method `get_field_name` use that.

Example:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    statistic = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=serializers.empty, statistic=None, **kwargs):
        super(MySerializer, self).__init__(instance=instance, data=data, **kwargs)
        self.statistic = statistic

    def get_statistic(self, obj):
        if self.statistic is None:
            return serializers.empty
        return self.statistic.get(obj.id, {})
```