# Djangorestframework - creating an api that calculates stats based on cards

Tags: django-rest-framework

djangorestframework, django 2.1, python 3.6

I have a certain api output that I'm looking to get from a djangorestframework api, but I'm not sure how to get it.

Basically, if you have a set of playing cards `3D,7H,8H,6S,7S,8S,4C,8C`, I want to compute some statistics for those cards and return it as an API call. The only way I've worked with djangorestframework is by returning the data from a model. I don't think that I'd need to make a model here, but maybe that's the right thing to do. I'm not sure. What's the best way to approach this?

```
input - 3D,7H,8H,6S,7S,8S,4C,8C

Output
 {
        'diamonds': {
            'count': 1,
            'sum': 3,
        },
        'hearts': {
            'count': 2,
            'sum': 15,
        },
        'spades': {
            'count': 3,
            'sum': 21,
        },
        'clubs': {
            'count': 2,
            'sum': 12,
        }
    }
```

Comment: can elaborate where are you stuck? Can you share any code you have written.

Comment: I wanted to do something like this _- I'll look at it later today to see if it is everything i need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677070/additional-field-while-serializing-django-rest-framework/22678883#22678883